# mysql distinct group_concat values

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have a bunch of user accounts that I need to create associations with based on DOB postcode etc.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT_WS(' , ' ,a.user_id , GROUP_CONCAT( b.user_id SEPARATOR ' , ' ) )
FROM tbl_users_details a,
tbl_users_details b
WHERE a.user_id != b.user_id
AND a.date_of_birth = b.date_of_birth
AND a.postcode = b.postcode
AND LEVENSHTEIN_RATIO( a.last_name , b.last_name ) > 60
GROUP BY a.user_id
```

To demonstrate my requirements...

If accounts 1 5 9 and 12 meet the criteria (ie these are the same people)

I will get 4 results in the format

```
1  , 5 , 9 , 12
5  , 1 , 9 , 12
9  , 1 , 5 , 12
12 , 1 , 5 , 9
```

I deally I'd like just 1,5,9,12

Any pointers would be great.

thanks people.

Comment: did you try to sort the tables?

Comment: @krankover its the same table so sorts matter not.

Comment: @alinoz - there are MANY records of many people that are needed - limiting result set not an option in this instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you be more clear in your requirement??

anyways try using Subquery like

```
Select CONCAT (user.i,',)
from 
(Select Distinct ...... --- ur old code ---- )
```

Thanks,
Shanmugam

Comment: yep discovered while you posted ;)

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would do something like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( user_id )
FROM tbl_users_details
GROUP BY date_of_birth, postcode, last_name
```

but the Levenshtein distance check makes this problematic, since there's actually no guarantee that `LEVENSHTEIN_RATIO(x, y) > n` and `LEVENSHTEIN_RATIO(y, z) > n` imply `LEVENSHTEIN_RATIO(x, z) > n`.  (For example, what if one of your users was named "Anderson", another "Addison" and a third "Atkinson"?)  You might want to consider using some other similarity estimation method that actually maps names into distinct groups, such as [soundex](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex) or [metaphone](http://www.atomodo.com/code/double-metaphone):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( user_id )
FROM tbl_users_details
GROUP BY date_of_birth, postcode, SOUNDEX(last_name)
```

Comment: That is very helpful. The reason the levenshtein has been used is because occasionally we hav a user who makes a minor typo on registration, for example we have an Anderson and an Adnerson living at same address with same dob - is pretty likely this is the same person. Working on a massive dataset and to be hones its truggling with queries to attempt this matches enmasse. BUt I am trying a few options - thanks for this nugget though - its alread proving useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can include ORDER BY clause into the [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function -

```
... GROUP_CONCAT(b.user_id SEPARATOR ' , ' ORDER BY b.user_id)
```

Comment: yes but as the group concat works on table b this would result in the same results. I need some way of ordering the combined concat AND group_concat as if it were one entity

Answer (score 0):

reckon I got it....

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(ida ORDER BY ida ASC SEPARATOR ' , ') ids
FROM
(SELECT LEAST(a.user_id, b.user_id ) idbase,a.user_id ida, b.user_id idb
FROM apollo.tbl_users_details a,
apollo.tbl_users_details b
WHERE a.user_id != b.user_id
AND a.date_of_birth = b.date_of_birth
AND a.postcode = b.postcode
AND LEVENSHTEIN_RATIO( a.last_name , b.last_name ) > 60
GROUP BY a.user_id) as sub
GROUP BY idbase;
```

Running on full data set to test..